# How can i check if request query value is empty such as ""?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am writing one Node.js component in that there is one API which will get query value from request. sometimes that query values will be empty such as `""` so i need to write one condition for that.

for example,

query will contain the values like this

```
 {
    name:"",
    start:"yyyy"
 }
```

so I need to write one condition to check whether name is empty or not .

i have written some thing like that

`if(name){}`

`if(name===""){}`

but it does not work then i have checked the string length it is giving 2 .

so how to write condition ?

Comment: have you tried `if(name==""){` ?

Comment: isn't that name part of an object?  wouldn't you have to so something like `object.name === ''`?

Comment: If the string length is giving 2, you might have empty spaces in there, or maybe it's an array. Can you try to output the actuval value of name in the console or something (like `console.log(">" + name + "<")`

Comment: it is the string taking from request query . ya i have tried if(name=="") but it  does not work ...

Comment: can you show the context of how you are getting this variable

Comment: var name = req.query.name ;

Comment: in console.log i got this  > ''"<

Comment: and do you have access to the code calling your api?

Comment: Try `if (name === '""'){}` (single quotes around double quotes - looks like your name is being set to a set of double quotes)

Comment: Well @Pete it's weird, the console.log output actually shows a space followed by 2 single quotes and a doublequote

Comment: My advice would be to fix the thing that is providing that as a result then (if you are expecting to get an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

If string length is 2 as you say. Then I assume that the following might work:

```
if(name===""""){} // <--this is just wrong.
```

Update:
I guess the problem is that the string consist of two spaces. So you could try:

```
if (name.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
    // Your Code
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit of a guess

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer as per the comments.
The problem was with the request send to the server. It is to be noted that we need not include double quotes for empty string. The problem above is occurring because the query string being used was

`www.bla.com?name=""`

Here the variable "name" was acquiring two double quotes as its value, which was meant to be empty. So instead of query string above, use the format below :

`www.bla.com?name=`

here the variable name correctly acquires the empty string as its value.

For multiple Variables use

`www.bla.com?name=&age=22`

Comment: could you please provide some more code. It seems to work fine on my machine.

Comment: app.get('/getVisitorInfo',function(req,res){

console.log(">" + req.query.stadiumName + "<");


  
  if(!req.query.stadiumName==="")
  {
   res.send("stadiumName")
  }
 });

Comment: app.get('/getVisitorInfo',function(req,res){

console.log(">" + req.query.stadiumName + "<");


  
  if(req.query.stadiumName==="")
  {
   res.send("stadiumName")
  }
 });

Comment: app.get('/getVisitorInfo',function(req,res){

console.log(">" + req.query.stadiumName + "<");


  
  if(!req.query.stadiumName)
  {
   res.send("stadiumName")
  }
 });

Comment: app.get('/getVisitorInfo',function(req,res){

console.log(">" + req.query.stadiumName + "<");


  
  if(req.query.stadiumName=="")
  {
   res.send("stadiumName")
  }
 });

Comment: from rest client I am sending get request like this http://localhost:3000/getVisitorInfo?stadiumName=''"

Comment: Here's the catch.You don't use quotes in query. 
`localhost:3000/getVisitorInfo?stadiumName=`

Comment: If you want to send multiple data, just use the syntax below:


`http://localhost:3000/bla?name=&username=ankur`

Comment: Hi @silvesterprabhu , could you please accept my answer if it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it comes from your query `localhost:3000/getVisitorInfo?stadiumName=''";`, it contains two single quotes followed by a doublequote, so do the following instead : `localhost:3000/getVisitorInfo?stadiumName=""`